# How to add pass class to class arguments and put in list

Tags: python, arrays, containers

I am new to python

There are several classes that need to be passed to the function of another class, I don't quite understand how to do this.

there is a class Driver:

```
class driver():
    type = "driver"
    def __init__(self, Name, Srnm, Exp):
        self.setName(Name)
        self.setSrnm(Srnm)
        self.setExp(Exp)

    def setName(self, t):
        self.__Name = t
    def setSrnm(self, t):
        self.__Srnm = t
    def setExp(self, t):
        self.__Exp = t
```

there is a class truck:

```
class truck():
    type = "car"
    def __init__(self, Number, Mark, CarCap):
        self.setNumber(Number)
        self.setMark(Mark)
        self.setCarCap(CarCap)
        
    def setNumber(self, t):
        self.__Number = t
    def setMark(self, t):
        self.__Mark = t
    def setCarCap(self, t):
        self.__CarCap = t
```

there is a class dirigeer:

```
class dirigeer():
    lst = []
    def add(self, c, d):
        self.lst.append([c,d])
```

main.py:

```
d1 = m1.driver('Vasya', 'Vasin', 4)
c1 = m1.truck('A666AA', 'Ford', 100)

c = m1.dirigeer
c.add(c1, d1)
```

If i do this without transferring data, then everything works out for me. If I try to pass to a class, then I get the following errors:

```
File "main.py", line 34, in <module>
    constructor()
File "main.py", line 18, in constructor
    c.add(c1, d1)
TypeError: add() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'c' and 'd'
```

Comment: Does `c = m1.dirigeer` need to be `c = m1.dirigeer()`?

Comment: Also, please read up on Python terminology. You're passing _objects_ of classes, not the classes themselves. Misunderstanding the terminology can make it hard to know what to look for when you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHrm9.png)

Just remove m1.